# Do we require a transit visa for a connecting flight in Sweden?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, airport-transfer, sweden

I'm an Indian citizen and I'm travelling from London to India through a connecting flight in Stockholm, Sweden. Do I need to have a Transit Sweden visa to catch my connecting flight?

Comment: Under criterion #4 in the earlier question, you appear to be OK;  Indian citizens do not require a transit visa for Sweden (though they do need transit visas to transit certain other Schengen countries.)

Answer (score -1):

A Visa is required, unless you qualify to transit without a visa:

Passengers transiting through Stockholm (ARN) and arriving from a non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight on the same calendar day to a third country which is not a Schengen Member State. They must:
- stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
- have documents required for the next destination.

Source: https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b